# What does the following code of ICOMAdminCatalog do?

Tags: delphi, com

I have came to following code for which i am not able to understand the meaning and expected output of the code.

Can anyone tell me what does the following code do?
**variable Declaration**

```
Cat : ICOMAdminCatalog;
Apps : ICatalogCollection;
App : ICatalogObject;
```

**Code for creation of IComAdminCatlog object and populate the same**

```
Cat := CoCOMAdminCatalog.Create;
Apps := Cat.GetCollection('Applications') as ICatalogCollection;
Apps.Populate;
```

Any suggestion or information will be helpful for me to understand the concept of the above.

Comment: It loads the 'Applications' COM+ catalog collection. See [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309561%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @TOndrej yes i have gone through the same documentation. but which applications is the questions. are they showing in the task manager or from somewhere else?

Comment: Go through it [again](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They are COM+ catalog [applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Start Menu, select Control Panel, select Administrative Tools, open Component Services, select Computers, select My Computer, select COM+ Applications. Those applications can be programatically be managed by ICOMAdminCatalog.